# Dynamically rendering an array of Components

Tags: reactjs

How do I write a function that takes an array of components and instantiates them all in its enclosing scope?

```
const = [component1, component2,...]

// into

<Component1 />
<Component2 />
...
```

Comment: `[Component1, Component2].map(Component => <Component />)`

Comment: @AndrewLi wouldn't that give me another array of components?

Comment: Should just be able to wrap them in a div. `<div>{components}</div>`.

Comment: @BradyHaden Thanks! How could I do that with a for loop? What would I return?

Comment: @S.W. What are you trying to accomplish with this loop? A React component should be pretty much self contained so it would be 'instantiated' when it is rendered to the DOM.

Comment: @BradyHaden I want to take an array of components passed as props into another component and make them share data. I wanted to be able to wrap them in a Context Provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your components with their props ready to use in the array you can use the array itself, cause it works the same as Fragment.
If you need to pass props to your component you can map through the array and pass props.

```
const Todo = ({id, done, text}) =>  (
  <li key={id}>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" disabled readOnly checked={done} /> 
      <span className={done ? "done" : ""}>{text}</span>
    </label>
  </li>
)
```

```
const Todos = [
    // Render with jsx
    <Todo text="Learn React" done={false} id={2} />,
    // Render with createElement
    React.createElement(Todo, {text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, id: 1}),
    // Render with function call (not possible all the time e.g. some ref cases)
    Todo({text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true , id: 3}),
]
```

```
const TodoApp = () =>  (
<ol>
 {[Todos]}
</ol>
)
```

Of course, you can alter the array before committing to the screen

```
const FancyMapperComponent({size}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {Array.from({length:size}).map((_, i) => (
        <li key={`unique-${i}`}>Text content {i}<li/>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

[demo in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KKTCondition/t2x08swy/6/)

Comment: How could I generate them in a way that lets me change their prop dynamically from the enclosing component?

Comment: you can map through a list of props and return newly generated component with dynamic props

Answer (score 2):

```js
const Example = (props) => {
  const context = {};

  const newProps = {
    a: '1',
    b: '2',
  }
  
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={context}>
      {[Component1, Component2].map((Component) => (
        <Component {...newProps} />
      ))}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it work to wrap them in a Context Provider?

Comment: Oh bless you kind sir!

Comment: Is there any way to generate them in a way that lets me change their props dynamically from the enclosing component?

Comment: @S.W. sure, I've updated my example code. You can define the new props, and then use the spread ... operator to add them to your child components.